# downloading home version for mac

Tags: home-edition

This is I think a trivial question but I did check against those already asked.

I am downloading Mathematica (home use). Very slow connection. So my Mac displayed the progress bar but this morning the bar is replaced in the downloads window with "mounting failed." When I double-click this icon it informs me the program can't be accessed because it is still downloading.

When I right-clicked "get info" on the dmg file it went from 2.07G to 4 KB over the course of a few minutes.

a. Has the download stopped? Been reversed? 
b. Is it possible to get the progress bar back to see what's happening?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I guess this is more of a question to be asked to the fellows of Wolfram- support. (or your ISP if this is just a question of connection quality)

Comment: It's a weekend, so I went out on a limb. It's a support issue but if someone has an answer it might help others similarly situated. It's not about the connection.

Comment: Daniel, welcome to Mathematica.SE.  As Sascha says this is sort of off-topic but I'll leave it open for a while since you're anxious for an answer.  Once you have a bit higher "reputation" you can make use of the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica) for this kind of question.

Comment: Okay thanks and Sascha's point taken.

Comment: Mr. Wizard already indicated this question was slated for eventual closure. No need to spend precious moments downvoting.

Comment: A good guess might be that the release of Mathematica 9 a couple of days ago is stressing the servers.

Comment: It's probably stressing the customer service reps. When I explained the problem to the tech folks they said many wireless users could not download and sent me to ask for hard media. Problem? Not available yet and no firm date! I was able to dowload using someone else's connection. Anyway thanks for keeping the question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution which might work for you too. When you use the *Home use* edition, then I assume you have another *Mathematica* licence at work or in university. What you can do is, that you download the dmg over a VPN connection with the fast speed of your office/university.

After that, you can use *scp* or an `ftp` or something similar to transfer it to your home at any speed you like without being afraid, that the browser or user portal does something weird.

Comment: No in fact I do not have another Mathematica license. Not sure why you assume that.

Comment: He's talking about the [Home Edition](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica-home-edition/), not a [home-use license](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/764).

Comment: @daniel As Brett commented: I assumed that because you wrote *home use* which is very different from *Home edition*. Sorry, but my answer still can help you, if you have access to VPN wich more bandwidth.

Comment: Your answer is helpful and I had something like that in mind as a possibility.  Thanks.

Comment: I was able to download using your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @daniel Then upvote and accept this answer. You should definitely read through the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq) to understand how up/downvoting works and what *reputation* is.